# adding maximum and minimum values in a 2D array, excluding the highest and lowest integers

Tags: c#

I have a 2D array and I want to output the sum of the values for each array individually but also exclude the maximum and minimum values from the calculation of that sum. E.G if array = { {2, 3, 4, 5}, {4, 5, 6, 7} }. then the code should exclude 2 and 5 from the first array and just add and output 9 (3 + 4), and then output 11 for the second array (5 + 6). Also if the array contains 2 ore more of the lowest value and two or more of the highest value it should exclude only 1 of those however many similar values E.G if the array = {2, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6} the code should output 20 (2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6).

I have attempted coding this myself however my values are not showing up. I think it might have something to do with my scores_total equalling 0 but I don't know how else to declare it.

any help would be appreciated.

results array is stored in main

```
static void JudgesTotal(int[,] results)
{
    int Minimum = results[0, 0];
    int Maximum = results[0, 0];
    int score_total = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < results.GetLength(0); i++)
    {
        score_total = score_total + results[i, j];
        if (Minimum > results[i, j])
        {
            Minimum = results[i, j];
        }

        if (Maximum < results[i, j])
        {
            Maximum = results[i, j];
        }

        score_total = score_total - (Maximum - Minimum);

        if (results[i, j] > results[i, j] + 1)
        {
            Console.Write("{0}", score_total);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add your code as a code sample block instead of image?

Comment: sorry I'm heaps tired and just want to get this done ahah apologies

Comment: what is a code sample block? I'm new to this

Comment: if performance doesn't matter, first determine min and max value in a loop and then use a second loop to actually add them.
Or use a given sorting function to sort the array and then let the loop iterate from index 1 to last-1.

Comment: okay I will give that a try

Comment: You need to reset your `Minimum` and `Maximum` at the beginning of the first loop, so you are not comparing to the min and max values of the previous loop.  You can set them to the first item `results[i, 0]`

Comment: Also your inequality operator is the wrong way round on your test for Maximum (thanks juharr)

Comment: @ChrisPetheram Actually the one for min is correct.  It's the one for max that is wrong.

Comment: @juharr - My mistake, thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean, so in the second loop assign Minimum and Maximum to results[i, 0].

Comment: Both your tests for maximum and minimum are checking whether the recorded limit is larger than the current element.
See juharr's answer to change your recorded Maximum if you find a larger value in the array.

Comment: @siklad96 I've posted an answer with the change you need.  The idea is that after you loop for `i=0` the max and min are set to whatever the max and min where for that array.  Then for `i=1` you need to reset them or your end up comparing to the the previous arrays min and max which could end up in you subtracting the wrong values if the previous min was less than the current and/or the previous max is more.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of problems with your code.  First you don't reset the `Minimum` and `Maximum` at the start of the next array.  Second you don't reset the `score_total` at the start of each new array.  Next, your comparison for the max value is wrong.  And finally you have to subtract out the min and max after the inner loop finishes.  Here's an example of how to fix all those issues.
Also I'm not clear on why you had `if(result[i,j] > result[i,j] + 1)` in there since it would only be `true` if `result[i,j]` was `int.MaxValue`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < results.GetLength(0); i++)
{
    if(results.GetLength(1) <= 2)
    {
        //There are either 0 items which would sum to 0
        //Or 1 item which is both the min and max and the sum should be 0
        //Or 2 items where one is the min and the other the max and the sum should be 0
        Console.WriteLine(0);
        continue;
    }

    long min = results[i,0];
    long max = results[i,0];
    long total = 0;
    for(int j = 0; j < results.GetLength(1); j++)
    {
        total += results[i,j];
        if(results[i,j] < min)
            min = results[i,j];
        if(max < results[i,j])
            max = results[i,j];
    }
    total -= (min + max);
    Console.WritLine(total);
}
```

Note I made the `min`, `max`, and the `total` of type `long` to avoid potential overflows.  `total` because summing up enough integers or large integers could result in a value that doesn't fit in an `int`.  Worse case is an array of size `int.MaxValue` where all the items are `int.MaxValue` and the `total` woudl be `int.MaxValue * int.MaxValue` and that will fit in `long`.  The `min` and `max` are `long` because we add them and `int.MaxValue + int.MaxValue` doesn't fit in `int`, but does fit in `long`.  Also the same ideas holds for `int.MinValue` as well.

Comment: hmm still doesn't seem to be showing :/ do you think it has anything to do with my score_total being 0?

Comment: @siklad96 There were more issues.  I've added code to show how to fix them all.

Comment: @siklad96 Also in the future please post the code as text.  It makes it easier for us to copy and paste it to help in answering your question.

Comment: thank you very much for this, I will take this on board I'm very new to stack overflow as you can probably guess. On a quick note what does total + and total - do? is that just another way of writing total = total + or - ?

Comment: @siklad96 Yes,  `n += k;` is short hand for `n = n + k;` and similarly `n -= k;` is short for `n = n - k;`.

Comment: @siklad96 FYI I just fixed it to work if the second dimension is less than 2 and short cut if it is equal to 2.  I'm assuming that in all three cases the sum should be zero, but you could handle each case differently if you choose.